# Error al migrar de SQLite3 a PostGreSQL: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql, sqlite, sqlite3

```
SELECT 
  ag.user_id, ag.user_des, ag.user_login, ag.user_pwd, ag.act_readers, 
  ag.h_reader, ag.email, ag.phone, ag.workgroup, ag.suspended, ag.accesstype, 
  ag.firekey, cli.tpdoc
FROM agenda ag 
INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON ag.user_id = cli.doc 
WHERE accesstype = 5 
ORDER BY user_des ASC
```

Usaba esta consulta en **SQLite3**, pero al migrar a **PostgreSQL** me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
"No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."
```

No entiendo que significa y ya intente varias cosas. ¿Podrán ayudarme?

Comment: Estás usando alias de tabla en las columnas del `select` pero no en el `where` o el `order`, aunque no creo que ese sea el problema. Aparte, ¿qué tipos tienes `accesstype`, `ag.user_id` y `cli.doc`?

Comment: A que te refieres con tipos?

Comment: ¿Son `integer`, `decimal`, `varchar`...?

Comment: Los 3 son de tipo Text

Comment: Entonces está ahí el problema, al hacer la comparación de `accesstype`, estás queriendo comprobar un `string` con un `int`.

Comment: @Kleith deberías poner eso como respuesta (referenciando la documentación al respecto si es posible)

Comment: Solo tengo que poner el accesstype = 5  como string,  accesstype = '5', muchas gracias.